# Php Gallery table

Tags: php, html, gallery

I need to make a table with preferable 4 - 5 pictures per row but instead it continues across my page. Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";

$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "imageupload";

$query = "SELECT id, url, name from images ";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die("Problem connecting.");
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("Bad Query.");

mysqli_close($connect);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{

    echo "<td>";

    echo "<td><h2><img src=" . $row['url'] . " width=150 height=150/></h2></td>";


    echo "<td><h2>" .$row['name'] . "</h2></td>";


    echo "</td>";
}
?>

<table>
```

Comment: You've included some code that looks like it's attempting to do what you need to do. What _does_ it do?

Comment: you closed your connection too early

Comment: and your `<table>` tag is out of place. Syntax: `<table>...</table>`. The `...` is your code.

Comment: Also, I don't actually see any `<tr>`s.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that too; thing's riddled with syntax errors, most of which HTML, one of which mysql.

Comment: So Davin; what do you see when you look at your HTML source? and `var_dump()`'ing the url row. Or, have you left the question?

Comment: It continues the pictures horizontally across the page. I'd like 4-5 pics per row instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
foreach($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    if($row['id'] % 4 == 0) { //Change it to 5 if you want 5 images per row
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "<td><img src='" . $row['url'] . "' /></td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```